# Filtering only lines having specific string in begining using python

Tags: python

I need a small help for filtering only required lines from notepad using python

Example :

**Input**

```
 - A MY NAME IS ANDY 
 - B MY NAME IS BANDY
 - C MY NAME IS CANDY
 - A MY NAME IS ANTRO
 - B MY NAME IS BANTRO
 - C MY NAME IS CANTRO
```

search only first string and check if it is B , it will print the corresponding line

**OUTPUT**

```
 - B MY NAME IS BANDY
 - B MY NAME IS BANTRO
```

Comment: I heard great things about `startswith()`...

Comment: have you tried documenting yourself on regex in python ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: What code are you using? It's not clear to me what we're helping with.

Comment: You need to provide details on what specifically you have tried and the issues with your code. Right now your question is too broad and off topic. If you don't know where to start then try to break down the problem into steps. Then you figure out the parts you know how to do and the parts you don't. Search the internet and books you have for answers to the parts you don't. Then post specific programming questions when you get stuck on code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multple ways. Asumming that the data is stored in a file called.txt you can read the file using

```
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

Then filter using the startswith method and print the result

```
filtered_list = [x for x in lines if x.startswith('- B')]
for item in filtered_list:
  print(item)
```

leads to

```
- B MY NAME IS BANDY
- B MY NAME IS BANTRO
```